# Getting GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT with depth texturing

Tags: java, opengl, textures, framebuffer, shadow-mapping

I have been trying to implement shadow-mapping for a long time, and I am using Lance Williams' technique (which is rendering the scene twice, once in light space and once in view space). However, when I call `glCheckFramebufferStatus` on `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, I get `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT`, *after* I have called `glFramebufferTexture2D` on it. I am confused, because that error is thrown when there isn't a texture or renderbuffer attached to the framebuffer, but I think I *do* have a texture attached to it.

Here is my code run in `init`:

```
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // generate stuff
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, ib);
    frameBuffer = ib.get(0);
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, ib);
    depthTexture = ib.get(0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE, depthTexture);

    // prevents 'shadow acne'
    gl.glPolygonOffset(2.5f, 0);
    // prevents multiple shadows
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // prevents (or expects!!!) pixel-y textures
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
    // store one value in all four components of pixel
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL2.GL_INTENSITY);

    gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1024, 1024, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL2.GL_FLOAT, null);
    gl.glDrawBuffer(GL2.GL_NONE);
    gl.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_NONE);
    int FBOStatus = gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    // FBOStatus == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT
```

**EDIT**: I ran this method in a practically empty project too (throwing the error)

Comment: What does `(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL2.GL_INTENSITY)` mean? How do you use `INTENSITY` as a mode?

Comment: It should set all four components of the output vector to one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I think I do have a texture attached to it.

No, you haven't.

Since

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE, depthTexture);
```

will only generate an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error because you meant `GL_TEXTURE_2D` here, you only have a name of a texture object, and never created the texture storage for that. Your `glTexImage2D` call will just affect some other texture object which happens to be bound at the time (or even texture object 0 in legacy GL).

Comment: This saved so much mental pain